# Unable to edit and save a file on remote machine using Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I am using Notepad++ 5.3.1. I want to edit and save files on a remote machine (both are running on Windows XP). I have granted the access privileges and security permissions in the folder containing the files.

When I try to save any of these files after editing in Notepad++, I get the following error.

```
 'Please check whether if this file is opened in another program'
```

There are no other places where the file has been opened but I still get this error. I was able to edit and save earlier but this error seems to be coming only since yesterday.

Comment: how are you connecting to the remote machine?

Comment: Are you sure nothing else is really holding the file open?

Comment: U have to open notepad++ as Administrator. As mentioned here [Super User Website](http://superuser.com/a/575167/152179)

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I have fixed the issue now. The problem was that though the permissions have been set properly on the root folder the subsequent child folders were not inheriting the access privileges. Therefore when I suddenly edited a file in one of the child folders this error cropped up. I went to the advanced tab under security settings of the root folder propeties and checked the option

```
 Replace permission entries on all child objects with entries shown here that apply to child objects
```

Thanks one and all

Answer (score 53):

Opening the editor (Notepad++) on administrator mode could have helped too!

Comment: I was trying to add an entry to my hosts file on my Windows machine and got that error message. By default, my PC wanted to open the hosts file with Notepad++.  Like nadh said, I found that right clicking on Notepad++ and opening it in administrator mode took care of this lock/security issue and allowed me to save.

Comment: nothing changes, windows 10

Answer (score 17):

gsk is correct! It's permissions!

Properties > Security > Edit > Users -> Allow (checked on everything) and then "OK" and "OK" so it saves all the settings.

Comment: this is the only solution that worked for me. opening notepad as admin didn't solve it. One other way was to copy the file to desktop and copy it back, but that is not practical

Comment: Seems to have worked, but i also restarted notepad++ in administrator mode, so might have also helped.... O_o

Answer (score 16):

Actually, it's a much simpler answer.

If you opened the file in a Windows Explorer window, and you have the preview pane enabled, it locks the file. If you deselect the file in the window, it will make the preview go away, and the file will be unlocked again.

I did a post of this [file locking problem](http://mitchfournier.com/2012/08/31/error-saving-an-html-file-in-windows-7-with-notepad/) on my blog, if you want more info and a screenshot.

Comment: Does Windows XP (the system the OP was using here) have such a preview mode?

Comment: this solved it, thank you

Comment: wow, this is really unbelievable.

Comment: doesn't help, (I even closed the folder and it didn't help)

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem with the file [C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)). I resolved it by opening the file by NotePad++ run as administrator.

To run Notepad++ (or any other program) as an administrator just right click on the application and select "Run As Administrator."

Comment: Perhaps "Run notepad++ as an Administrator"  is the best & the easiest answer among all. Believe me it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Another possible reason I just discovered:

Antivirus software can block access to the file, even though the ACL permissions (under Security) are correct.

I just noticed that because on one occasion (not sure if it was due to my attemt to save the file or change it's ownership to administrator) the antivirus-software displayed a notification window that the access was blocked.

Answer (score 3):

Two things come to mind to try:

1. Map a drive and connect using mapped drive instead of a [URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier).
2. Make sure you have permissions to create files on remote server as well. Sometimes these text editors create a temporary file before re-writing the saved information.

This also might be a question better suited for [Server Fault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Fault).

I hope this helps!

Comment: I don't think Notepad++ writes temporary files during editing - the only time I've seen it write temporary files is when it detects a crash, for file recovery later.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error while using WAMP. I went to the file location (www folder), right clicked and refreshed the folder.

Answer (score 3):

My problem involved WinSCP and the solution I did was to uncheck "`External editor opens each file in separate window (process)`" in editor preferences.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem sometime back and didn't understand why, recently when it happened I simply granted full control to my user account for the root folder where my files were. After that the error did not appear again, just like GSK said back there.

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple..
Right click on  Notepad++ shortcut -> Run as administrator.

Answer (score 1):

I opened the file using Notepad++ as an administrator, but I still had the same issue:

> Please check whether if this file is opened in another program

Then I made a copy of the file in another location followed by a copy and replace of the original file. This solved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

Open Notepad++. Right click -> Properties -> **"find your name"** under the *Security* tab -> right click allow for read, write, read and execute, full control.

Apply changes. Now save the content you would like to save.

Answer (score 0):

Permission of administrator (operating system User), as it has been blocked. So log-in as administrator and give the share permission to another user (where you want to edit).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when setting up the [Apache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) webserver and [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP). This was due to the [UAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) on Windows 7. It's is not because you have the file open anywhere else. Try opening Notepad++ as administrator. Either right click Notepad++ shortcut and choose run as administrator or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> and click Notepad++ shortcut. Then open the file you want to edit from within Notepad++.

This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

This issue can occur when another user (e.g. administrator) owns the file and does not give everyone else write access. Here is how to give write access too all users for all files in current directory and all sub-directories.

Open an **administrative console**, go the the root of the directory where the file(s) are. Type:

```
icacls "." /grant Everyone:(F) /T
```